# How can I quickly kill all threads running a specific script?

Tags: multithreading, command-line, grep, ps

I found a bunch of long running scripts (`script.php`) on a server and want to kill them all.

```
ps aux | grep script.php

user   6270  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug20   2:18 php /path/to/script.php
user   6290  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   15:34   0:00 php /path/to/script.php
user   7439  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug18   2:05 php /path/to/script.php
user   8270  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug17   7:18 php /path/to/script.php
user   8548  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug15   0:15 php /path/to/script.php
user   8898  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug17   3:01 php /path/to/script.php
user   9875  0.1  0.1 375580 50476 ?   Ss   Aug18   2:18 php /path/to/script.php
```

I can kill them one at a time like so:

```
kill 6270
```

But how can I kill all of them at once?

Answer (score 2):

With Linux:

```
pkill -f "php /path/to/script.php"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the pkill command.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill and here  http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/pkill/

Must be something like 'pkill -n script.php'